# implicit function theorem and harmonic mapping

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, laplacian, harmonic-functions

We are given two Riemannian manifolds $M,N$ of dimension $m$ and $n$ and a function $G \colon M \times N \to \mathbb{R}^n$ which satisfies the assumptions of the implicit function theorem, meaning that there exists a smooth map $\Phi \colon M \to N$ which locally parameterizes - with respect to $M$ - the $0$-level set of $G$: $G(x,\Phi(x)) = 0$.

I'm looking for a criterion on $G$ in order to check that the map resulting from the implicit theorem is harmonic as a map between two Riemannian manifolds, if such criterion exists. Recall that a map is said to be *harmonic* if the associate tension field $\mathrm{Tr}(\nabla d u)$ vanishes.

I tried to do some computation but I can't handle them well enough to say something interesting.

Does anyone have an idea on the question?

Comment: The  maps  arising the implicit function theorem make one to remember the concept of "section" So as a possible related question one can ask the following: Let $X:M\to TM$  be  a  vector  field on a  Riemannian manifold $M$ whose tangent bundle is equiped  with the sasaki metric. Is it true to say that $X$, as a map is  harmonic if  and  only if its  corresponding 1-form on $M$ arising from inner product by $X$ is  a  harmonic form. May be it has an obvious answer but i  am not sure about it. I think this question  has an indirect  similarity to your question.